# Unfortunately App Has Stopped

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I am using Actionbarsherlock library For Slide Menu ....When I add More Than three item in Slide menu ..then App Crashed and giving me ....error

i dont to how to Correct error **`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException lenth=3 index=3`**

thank u in advance

Log Cat giving error

```
08-06 16:45:14.339: E/AndroidRuntime(15732): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=3; index=3
 08-06 16:45:14.339: E/AndroidRuntime(15732):   at com.example.phonebook.MenuListAdapter.getView(MenuListAdapter.java:63)
```

Edit

this Is My SlidingMenuDrawer

```
Fragment fragment1 = new Welcome();
Fragment fragment2 = new MeetPeople();
Fragment fragment3 = new FriendsActivity();
Fragment fragment4=new SettingProfile();
private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
private CharSequence mTitle;


// UserModel user=(UserModel)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("User");
@Override
public  void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Get the view from drawer_main.xml
    setContentView(R.layout.drawer_main);
    UserModel user=(UserModel) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("User");

    // Get the Title
    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

    // Generate title
    title = new String[] { "My Profile", "Meet people",
            "My Friends","Setting" };

    // Generate subtitle
    subtitle = new String[] { "", "",
            "" };

    // Generate icon
    icon = new int[] { R.drawable.action_about, R.drawable.action_settings,
            R.drawable.collections_cloud ,R.drawable.setting_iconn};

    // Locate DrawerLayout in drawer_main.xml
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    // Locate ListView in drawer_main.xml
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_drawer);

    // Set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer
    // opens
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow,
            GravityCompat.START);

    // Pass string arrays to MenuListAdapter
    mMenuAdapter = new MenuListAdapter(SlidingMenuDrawer.this, title, subtitle,
            icon);

    // Set the MenuListAdapter to the ListView
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(mMenuAdapter);

    // Capture listview menu item click
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

    // Enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
    // between the sliding drawer and the action bar app icon
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open,
            R.string.drawer_close) {

        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onDrawerClosed(view);
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // Set the title on the action when drawer open
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
        }
    };

    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        selectItem(0);
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {

        if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList)) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList);
        }
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

// ListView click listener in the navigation drawer
private class DrawerItemClickListener implements
        ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        selectItem(position);
    }
}

private void selectItem(int position) {

    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    // Locate Position
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
           Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            UserModel user=(UserModel)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("User");
            String User_name=user.getUser_Full_Name();
            String url=user.getUser_Image();
            bundle.putString("User_Fullname", User_name);
            bundle.putString("User_image", url);
            Welcome fragment1 = new Welcome();
            fragment1.setArguments(bundle);
          ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment1);

        break;
    case 1:
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment2);
        //ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment2);
        break;
    case 2:
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment3);
        break;
    case 3:
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment4);
        break;
    }

    ft.commit();
    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);

    // Get the title followed by the position
    setTitle(title[position]);
    // Close drawer
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggles
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    mTitle = title;
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
}
```

}

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this/23353174#23353174

Comment: @NiekHaarman What Is it Not relating My Question

Comment: @Prag'sシ i edited My Code ...See Above

Comment: where are you getting error?

Comment: See Case 3 in Switch case 

case 3:
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment4);
        break;
when Add this App Crash ..I remove Case 3 App is Running Properly

Comment: When I click On Error Curser Goes MenuListAdaptor
 at this line 
 txtSubTitle.setText(mSubTitle[position]);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i could see that there is difference between two arrays..

```
title = new String[] { "My Profile", "Meet people","My Friends","Setting" }; // 4 values

subtitle = new String[] { "", "", "" }; //3 values
```

add one more value to subtitle array..

Comment: thanx prag and sorry its my mistake ..u saved my time

Comment: prag ....may i ask a question ....i want to diplay testview on image ...
myacount.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_row);
giving me error here 
nullpointer

Comment: plzz help i know its another question

Comment: i want to show textView On Image .
and using this line 
myacount.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_row);

but giving me error nullpointer at this line 
please tell me how to show textview on Image

Comment: may be you haven't define value to myaccount variable.. check it out that myaccount is null or not..

Comment: TextView myaccount; Defined Like This

Comment: `myaccount = (Textview)findViewById(R.id.textviewid);` and make sure that textview is in same layout you defined in `setContentView()`...

Answer (score 1):

You have 4 elements in `title` array and only 3 in `subtitle`. You're passing both arrays to `MenuListAdapter` and the exception is its `getView()` you didn't post.